# Notepad++ autocomplete text file adjustments?

Tags: text, autocomplete, notepad++

I would like to have the Notepad++ autocomplete feature

1. ignore dashes
2. include apostrophes

when working on plain text files. I cannot find a plain text XML definition file in the autocomplete directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\APIs\

Is there any way to change the standard search functionality for plain text files in Notepad++?

[image: Two scenarios I would like to fix.]

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you can change the search functionnality, but you can create a `normal.xml` file under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\APIs\` directory to change the autocomplete feature for normal text files

Comment: This does not seem to work to solve my main problem, though the normal.xml does work for autocompletion of text files. Do you have any examples that would answer the dash and contraction question?

Answer (score 1):

**QuickText is a free plugin for Notepad++ that you can use to add text snippets to the application. You define a tag and substitution text, and only need to type the text in Notepad++ and press Tab afterwards to replace it automatically with the selected substitution text.**

credits:http://www.ghacks.net/2014/02/22/work-text-snippets-notepad/

OR

I Personally Suggest You to try Sublime Text and its is the Most Customize able Text Editor which may be Extended to your own Needs. It is the Best Text Editor in the Current scenario.